# Java Program Add double Quote in all the line

Tags: java, opencsv

I'm writing a simple program that take a csv file and produce a csv with a new column. My problem is: the program quote the old columns and all the columns. 
Below my code

```
public class CSVmodifier {

    public static void modify(String Path,String Escape) throws IOException {
        int i=0;
        String filename = new File(Path).getName().toString();
        //setName(string) modify the original filename
                String fileoutname = setName(filename);
        File file= new File(fileoutname);
        try {
            FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file);
            Reader reader = 
                        Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(Path));
            CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader);
            CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(out);
            String[] nextRecord;
            while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
                int dimension = nextRecord.length;
                String[] newline = new String[dimension+1];
                int y = 0;
                                //formatNumber create a string number with 9 
                                //zero in the front-> 1 > "000000001"
                newline[0]=formatNumber(i+1);
                while(y<dimension) {
                    newline[y+1] = nextRecord[y];
                    y++;
                }
                i+=1;
                csvWriter.writeNext(newline);
            }
            csvWriter.close();


        } finally {


        }
    }

    public static String formatNumber(int i) {
        String formatted = String.format("%09d", i);
        return formatted;
    }


}
```

my sample is :

```
"John","Doe","120 jefferson st.","Riverside", "NJ", "08075"
```

the wrong output is :

```
"000000001","""John""",""Doe"",""120 jefferson st."",""Riverside"", ""NJ"", ""08075"""
```

I cannot upload the file, but i'll show you a sample file (input line) that give the same problem:

```
'1231';'02512710795';'+142142';'2019/12/12';'statale';'blablabla';'iradsasad';'-123131';'+414214141'; 
'003';'08206810965';'+000000001492106';'2019/06/23';'Scuola statale elemetare';'Ola!'
```

There Output line:

```
'000000001';"'1231';'02512710795';'+142142';'2019/12/12';'statale';'blablabla';'iradsasad';'-123131';'+414214141'; "
'000000002';"'003';'08206810965';'+000000001492106';'2019/06/23';'Scuola statale'; "
```

Comment: We will need to see your formatNumber function to help

Comment: i'll add it, but the problem is in the old line that have a double quote for the entire line and a double quote for every old columns. Added the formatNumber function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your `CSVWriter` class is `com.opencsv.CSVWriter`.
You are using [csvWriter.writeNext(String[])](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/AbstractCSVWriter.html#writeNext(java.lang.String[])), which is a shortcut for `writeNext(nextLine, true);` ([JavaDoc](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/AbstractCSVWriter.html#writeNext(java.lang.String[],%20boolean))).
The second parameter, which is always true in this case, is `applyQuotesToAll`:

> True if all values are to be quoted. False applies quotes only to values which contain the separator, escape, quote, or new line characters.

So all you need to do, is changing this line:

```java
csvWriter.writeNext(newline)
```

to this:

```java
csvWriter.writeNext(newline, false);
```

Comment: Thanks this solve, the double quotation. but not the other problem:                                        000000001,"John,Doe,120 jefferson st.,Riverside, NJ, 08075"

Comment: Hm, looks like CSVReader does not recognize your separator and assumes the whole line as one entry. Which version of OpenCSV do you use?

Comment: Can you upload your *.csv file somewhere? To me it looks like the file may be malformed.

Comment: OpenCSV version 4.1, i cannot upload the data, but i'll write two sample line.

Comment: Can you add the source lines to the two output lines you posted?

Comment: posted in the question message, the input the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196145/discussion-between-michael-a-schaffrath-and-claudio-gugliotta).

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, check and let me know. Just change the logic in while block it replaces multiple double quotes to a single quote.

```
public class CSVmodifier {

public static void modify(String Path, String Escape) throws IOException {
    int i = 0;
    String filename = new File(Path).getName().toString();
    //setName(string) modify the original filename
    String fileoutname = setName(filename);
    File file = new File(fileoutname);
    try {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file);
        Reader reader
                = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(Path));
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader);
        CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(out);
        String[] nextRecord;
        while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            int dimension = nextRecord.length;
            String[] newline = new String[dimension + 1];

            int y = 0;
            //formatNumber create a string number with 9 
            //zero in the front-> 1 > "000000001"
            newline[0] = formatNumber(i + 1);
            while (y < dimension) {
                newline[y + 1] = nextRecord[y].replace("\"\"", "\"");
                if (newline[y + 1].startsWith("\"") && newline[y + 1].endsWith("\"")) {
                    newline[y + 1] = newline[y + 1].substring(1, newline[y + 1].length() - 1);
                }
                y++;
            }
            i += 1;
            csvWriter.writeNext(newline);
        }
        csvWriter.close();

    } finally {

    }
}

public static String formatNumber(int i) {
    String formatted = String.format("%09d", i);
    return formatted;
}


}
```